# storing vector for a key in map in c++ and accessing the vector for key by iterating through map

Tags: c++

How do create a vector for a certain key in map in c++ and how to access them ?
suppose i accept data in this format

```
   100 6 7
   56 7 8
   100 90 8
   100 8 9
```

Here 100 and 56 in first column are keys and for key 100 i need to create a vector containing elements 6 7 90 8 8 9
and for key 56 ,vector should be 7 8
.How can we do this in c++ and at same time how to access the vector for a certain key in c++?
I tried to inset vector a key this way but could not access the vector for key by iterating through map .

```
 int k;
cin>>k;
for(int i=1;i<=k;i++){
    int r,c1,c2;
    cin>>r>>c1>>c2;
     mymap[r].push_back(c1);
     mymap[r].push_back(c2);

}
```

HOW can we do it in c++ using map ?

Comment: You *do* know how to iterate over a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)? You do know that the iterator "points" to a [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)? Can you please elaborate on the problems you have? And if possible please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i am finding it difficult to access vector the key .can you   write a code as how to acess elements for a key ?? say for key 100 ,i should have the vector  6 7 90 8 8 9 to get printted

Comment: You seem to already know that `mymap[r]` gives you access to a vector, so you can call `push_back` on it. How about trying `mymap[r].begin()` and `mymap[r].end()`?

Comment: "could not access the vector for key by iterating through map ". Please elaborate. You don't need to iterate through a map in order to access a value for a certain key. You avcess it by writing `mymap[key]`. What exactly have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Key is unique. Since you have duplicate keys in the input, which you append -> you may want to do a map lookup. If the pair <key, vector> exists you just append the data with vector.pushback(..). If key does not exist, create a vector, pushback data and then emplace the the pair into the map.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a map, then what you want to do is keep adding to the vector that's associated with the key.

The following example shows how to do this:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

typedef std::map<int, std::vector<int>> MapV;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MapV mymap;
    string line;

    // get one line of data
    while (getline(cin, line))
    {
        // use a string stream to parse the data
        istringstream strm(line);
        int key, data;

        // first value is the key
        strm >> key;

        // all other values are the data
        while (strm >> data)
        {
            // the magic is here.
            auto pr = mv.insert(make_pair(key, std::vector<int>()));

            // add item to the vector
            pr.first->second.push_back(data);
        }
    }
}
```

The most important part of the code is this line:

```
    auto pr = mv.insert(make_pair(key, std::vector<int>()));
```

The [std::map::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) function will return a `std::pair`, denoting the iterator to the inserted item as the `first` of the pair, or if the key exists, the existing iterator to the key that already exists.

Then all we need to do is to take that return value, access the `second` (which is the vector), and merely `push_back` onto that vector.

See this [live example](http://ideone.com/kc4rXQ)